# CodeIgniter invoke variable from another function in the same controller

Tags: codeigniter

I have a problem. I want to access to a variable from another function. let me explain.

Controller

```
public function obtener_oplataforma_usuarios() {

$this->load->helper('form');

$this->load->model('usuarios_model');

$plataforma = $this->input->post('id_plataforma');

$data['records'] = $this>usuarios_model>obtener_plataformas_usuarios($plataforma);

$this->load->view('vista_plataforma_usuarios', $data);

}

function grupos($grupo){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('usuarios_model');
    $plataforma = 'BaD'; 
    $data['records'] = $this->usuarios_model->obtener_grupos($plataforma, $grupo);
    $this->load->view('vista_plataforma_usuarios', $data);       

}
```

Model

```
function obtener_grupos($plataforma, $grupo){
    $this->db->select('*');

    $this->db->from('usuarios');

    $this->db->where('Plataforma', $plataforma);

    $this->db->where('grupos', $grupo);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();

}
```

I want to access to the variable platforma in the function `obtener_oplataforma_usuarios` from the function `obtener_grupos` I tried different things and I still have problems.

Can you help me to solve this issue. and I want to do that because I want to make a query with two validations one is group and the other platforma. My problem is the second one. I recibe the information of plataforma fine from a from this is in the function `obtener_oplataforma_usuarios` and is fine but I do not how to read this variable from the other function.

Answer (score 0):

you lose minuses (-)  in pointers :)

```
$data['records'] = $this>usuarios_model>obtener_plataformas_usuarios($plataforma);
```

must be:

```
$data['records'] = $this->usuarios_model->obtener_plataformas_usuarios($plataforma)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a private variable in your class.

- Create the variable above your __construct function, `private $plataforma`
- Set the default value in your __construct function
- Set and get in your public function using `$this->plataforma`

Implemented in your code:

```
private $plataforma;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->plataforma = "";
}

public function obtener_oplataforma_usuarios() {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('usuarios_model');
    $this->plataforma = $this->input->post('id_plataforma');

    $data['records'] = $this>usuarios_model>obtener_plataformas_usuarios($this->plataforma);
    $this->load->view('vista_plataforma_usuarios', $data);
}

function grupos($grupo){
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->model('usuarios_model');
    $data['records'] = $this->usuarios_model->obtener_grupos($this->plataforma, $grupo);
    $this->load->view('vista_plataforma_usuarios', $data);       
}
```